# Converting Inline back to WatermarkTextBox

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I am using the WPF toolkit for its `WatermarkTextBox` control.

My application dynamically concatenates text strings and placeholders for a user to fill in the blanks.

```
foreach(var e in elements)
{
    if (isText)
    {
        LetterText.Inlines.Add(new Run
        {
            Text = e,
            BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Center
        });
    }
    else
    {
        LetterText.Inlines.Add(new WatermarkTextBox
        {
            Watermark = e
        });
    }

    isText = !isText;
}
```

This works quite well, but my problem occurs when I want to reassemble the text:

```
foreach(var inline in LetterText.Inlines)
{
    if (inline.GetType() == typeof(Run))
    {
        sb.Append(((Run)inline).Text);
    }
    else if (inline.GetType() == typeof(WatermarkTextBox))
    {
        var wtb = inline as WatermarkTextBox;
        sb.Append(wtb.Text);
    }
}
```

This fails at compile time with 'Cannot convert Inline to WatermarkTextBox' (without the else clause, the conversion from `Inline` to `Run` works fine).

How can I get the text from the `WatermarkTextBox`?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
            if (inline.GetType() == typeof(Run))
            {
                sb.Append(((Run)inline).Text);
            }
            else if (inline.GetType() == typeof(InlineUIContainer))
            {
                var container = inline as InlineUIContainer;
                var wtb = container.Child as WatermarkTextBox;

                if (wtb !=null)
                    sb.Append(wtb.Text);
            }
```

I don't know why the `InlineUIContainer` does not also get implicitly created for `Run` elements